# Can you remove the HTML Field Prefix from strongly typed models in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, view

I have a view model like this:

```
public class EditVM
{
  public Media.Domain.Entities.Movie Movie       { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Genre>          Genres      { get; set; }
}
```

Movie is the real entity I wish to edit. Genres is simply present to populate a drop down. I would prefer that when I call:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movie.Title)
```

inside my strongly typed view that the input control have a name = `"Title"` instead of `"Movie.Title"`

I do not wish to split my view into partial views or lose my strongly typed view by using `ViewData` or the like.

Is there a way to express to the View that I do not wish to have the `Movie.` prefix? I noticed that you can set:

```
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "x";
```

in the controller, but unfortunately it seems only to allow adding an **additional** prefix. Setting it to `""` does nothing.

Is there any work around for this? Or am I stuck with the unfortunate prefix that isn't really necessary in this case if I wish to keep strongly typed views and lambdas?

Thanks for any help.

**Update:**

Here's the controller actions to maybe make things a bit clearer.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
  var vm = new EditVM
  {
    Movie  = id.HasValue ? _movieSvc.Find(id.Value) : new Movie(),
    Genres = AppData.ListGenres()     
  };
  return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public void Edit([Bind(Prefix = "Movie")]Movie m)
{
   _movieSvc.AddOrUpdateMovie(m); //Exceptions handled elsewhere
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, in order to do what you want you would have to rewrite the Html helpers, and then you would have to write your own model binder.  Seems like a lot of work for minimal gain.

The only choice is a Partial view in which you pass the Movie object as the model.  However, this would require you to write your own model binder to have it be recognized.

The reason you have to do m.Movie.Title is so that the ID has the correct name, so the model binder can recognize it as a member of your model.

Based on your update:

Your options are:

1. Use non-strongly typed helpers.
2. Use a partial view.
3. Rewrite the stronly typed helpers
4. Don't use the helpers at all, and write the values to the HTML

Personally, i'd just use 1 or 2, probably 2.

EDIT:

Based on your update above.  Change your code to this (note, Genres does not get posted back to the server, so m.Genres will just be null on postback):

```
[HttpPost] 
public void Edit(EditVM m) 
{ 
   _movieSvc.AddOrUpdateMovie(m.Movie); //Exceptions handled elsewhere 
}
```

EDIT:

I did just think of an alternative to this.  You could simply do this:

```
@{ var Movie = Model.Movie; }
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Movie.Title)
```

However, if there was a validation error, you would have to recreate your EditVM.

Comment: I don't think I'd need to write a model binder. The `GET` version of my edit action uses EditVM because it requires all that data. But the `POST` version only expects to receive a Movie object. If the name attributes were simply "Title", etc. it would bind just fine.

Comment: So you're using a differnt model in your post than you do in your get and view.  That can be confusing, and why you're running into problems.  This is not the "happy path".  You're going to have to compromise on something.  See my update.

Comment: Yeah, it's the compromise I'm looking to avoid. BTW I think you mean to say it's the name property rather than the id that the model binder uses. I get the impression you think I'm doing something off the reservation here in terms of how I'm going about creating an edit action. I thought what I was doing was fairly common. Don't you ever have drop downs as part of the entities you edit? How do you approach the problem differently? Do you typically create partial views just for a drop down control? How do you populate drop downs and not have the GET/POST actions have dif parameters?

Comment: @C.J. - I was using ID generically, not specifically to refer to the Html ID field, but yeah.. Name is more correct.  I don't really understand what Dropdowns have to do with the problem.  Why don't you just take the EditVM class as the parameter to your Post method?  That's the preferred way to do it because if your model fails to validate you need to pass the original model back again anyways in order to keep ModelState correct.

Comment: @C.J. - I really don't understand why you think you need different Post methods just because you have dropdowns... that really makes no sense to me.  Dropdowns are just fields in your form, they don't affect which model you have.

Comment: I don't have different POST methods. I have 2 actions both called Edit. One that responds to GET requests which renders the view and another edit action that responds to POST from that view.

Comment: Also the POST is done via Ajax so I do not need to re-render the view on error. As for why I don't post EditVM it's because it seems a poor choice to me to POST data other than the movie entity. That's the only thing being edited. And the server has no need of the extra data to do a update/insert of a movie.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7085/discussion-between-c-j-and-mystere-man)

Comment: @C.J. - In your example, the Movie data is the only thing that would get posted even while using the EditVM model.  The only things that get posted are only those things within your form.  What model you use is only the CONTAINER that the model binder matches up to the posted data.  Using EditVM for your model won't post any more data than what you're doing.

Comment: Yup True. But I think it looks odd for the action to be expecting data it won't get.

Comment: Quite unfortunate indeed that those helpers hijack the control of our fields names/ids. Unfortunately it looks like we should either accept those sometimes unneeded prefixes and handle them with `Bind Prefix` on post action and adjust all custom js/css selector, or give up html helpers to retain full control of our html (my choice).

Answer (score 1):

> I have a view model like this

I think that you might have some misunderstanding about what a view model is. A view model shouldn't contain any reference to your domain models which is what those `Movie` and `Genre` classes seem to be. I mean creating a new class that you suffix with `VM` and in which you stuff all your domain models as properties is not really a view model. A view model is a class that is specifically designed to meet the requirements of your view.

A much more correct view model would looks like this:

```
public class EditVM
{
    public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GenreViewModel> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

and in your view you would have:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.MovieTitle)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Genres)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with you about view models. Perhaps I use the term more loosely than you, but I choose to call the data required by the view to render itself the "View Model". Regardless of what you choose to cal it though, if a class can be formed from existing classes in my Domain that matches that need, I don't see using them as being "incorrect".

Comment: @C.J. - it's not "incorrect" to use them in your view (well, it's not advised, but you can certainly do it), it's "incorrect" to call them a View Model.  Darin is absolutely correct, a View Model is a model that is customized to the view, not simply packaging your Domain models together.  At best, i'd call it a Pseudo-View Model.  There's not really to agree or disagree about, the definition of a View Model is pretty clear.

Comment: Would you say Steven Walther who was Senior Program Manager on the Microsoft ASP.NET team has it wrong in this post as well? http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx

Comment: @C.J. - I fail to understand what the reference article has to do with using domain models in your view.  In fact, there is nothing in that article that references a domain model.  In fact, his models are clearly his UI models, not his domain models.  If they were domain models, they would exist in a different layer or project.

Comment: Those classes are the ones that get persisted so I consider them the domain despite the solution not carving them into a separate project.

Comment: We're getting sidetracked, but I believe a VM can be a wrapper for Domain classes. If your view needs additional info beyond the domain such as a checkbox for if the user wants to add another movie then I can see creating a VM specific to the view so as not to dirty up the domain. Then you need to map between vm/domain and you do more work. My domain maps to my UI exactly so wrapping the domain objects is a good preactive IMO in this scenario because it's cleaner and less code. I understand you think that's bad but I hope we can be friends anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to either use the `TextBox(string name, object value)` overload instead of the `TextBoxFor`:

```
@Html.TextBox("Title", Model.Movie.Title)
```

You could also specify the input tag HTML instead of using a helper.

Another option is to take EditVM as your postback parameter.  This is what I would do.  My post action parameter is always the same type of the .cshtml model.  Yes there will be properties like lists that are null, but you just ignore those.  It also allows you to gracefully handle post errors as well because if there is an error you'll need to return an instance of that view model anyhow, and have the values they submitted included.  I usually have private methods or DB layer that handles retrieving the various lists that go into the ViewModel, since those will be empty on postback and will need to be repopulated, while not touching the properties that were in the post.

With your post method as it is now, if you need to return the same view, you've gotta create a new EditVM and then copy any posted values into it, and still populate the lists.  With my method, you eliminate one of those mapping steps.  If you are posting more than one thing, are you going to have umpteen different parameters on your post action?  Just let them all come naturally into a single parameter typed to the EditVM of the View.  While maybe having those null properties in the VM during the postback feels icky, you get a nice predictable consistency between View and postback IMO.  You don't have to spend alot of time thinking about what combination of parameters on your post method will get you all the pieces of data from the form.